# Llave compuesta primaria que al mismo tiempo es foránea con EF core Fluent Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, code-first

Necesito crear la siguiente relación: Tabla cliente , tabla proyecto y tabla clienteProyecto donde cliente proyecto tiene los campos : codigo cliente y codigoProyecto únicamente. Donde codigo cliente y codigoProyecto son llaves primarias ambos y al mismo tiempo llaves foráneas:

**Clase MobileCliente:**

```
 [Key]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool Estado { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Codigo")]
        public virtual ClienteProyecto ClienteProyecto { get; set; }
```

**Clase MobileProyecto:**

```
[Key]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool Estado { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Codigo")]
        public virtual ClienteProyecto ClienteProyecto { get; set; }
```

**Clase ClienteProyecto:**

```
 [StringLength(100)]
        public string CodigoCliente { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string CodigoProyecto { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MobileCliente> MobileCliente { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MobileProyecto> MobileProyecto { get; set; }
```

**La llave compuesta la declaré en el contexto principal de esta forma:**

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ClienteProyecto>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.CodigoCliente, t.CodigoProyecto });
```

Sin embargo al tratar de ejecutar la migración para crear las tablas con code first me tira este error:

> **The relationship from 'MobileCliente.ClienteProyecto' to 'ClienteProyecto.MobileCliente' with foreign key properties {'Codigo'
>   : string} cannot target the primary key {'CodigoCliente' : string,
>   'CodigoProyecto' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a
>   principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this
>   relationship.**

Comment: No he usado ef core, pero por lo que se ve, Clase Proyecto (al igual que cliente), deberían tener dos propiedades relacionadas con `ClienteProyecto`, ya que este va a tener una clave primaria compuesta, por ende, para ubicar un objeto de tipo ClienteProyecto relacionado, debe conocer su clave completa, me explico?

Comment: Donde está el Modelo `MobileCliente` ?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta ahí esta

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Le comprendo pero estaría agregando campos innecesarios. Más bien lo que necesitaria sería poder decirle en el atributo [ForeignKey("")] la forma de especificarle la columna a la que hace referencia o algo por el estilo para que ef lo entienda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listo. Al fin lo logré.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clases debían quedar de la siguiente forma:

**Clase MobileCliente:**

```
[Key]
[StringLength(100)]
public string CodigoCliente { get; set; }
[Required]
[StringLength(200)]
public string Descripcion { get; set; }
[Required]
public bool Estado { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<MobileClienteProyecto> MobileClienteProyecto { get; set; }
```

**Clase MobileProyecto:**

```
[Key]
[StringLength(100)]
public string CodigoProyecto { get; set; }
[Required]
[StringLength(200)]
public string Descripcion { get; set; }
[Required]
public bool Estado { get; set; }    

public virtual ICollection<MobileClienteProyecto> MobileClienteProyecto { get; set; }
```

**Clase MobileClienteProyecto:**

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
public string CodigoCliente { get; set; }
[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
public string CodigoProyecto { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CodigoCliente")]
public virtual MobileCliente MobileClientes { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CodigoProyecto")]
public virtual MobileProyecto MobileProyectos { get; set; }
```

**Y la declaración de la llave compuesta en la clase del  contexto:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MobileClienteProyecto>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.CodigoCliente, t.CodigoProyecto });
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba a renombrar las claves principales `[Key]` del las tablas `MobileCliente` y `MobileProyecto` de esta forma:

**Clase MobileCliente:**

```
    [Key]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CodigoCliente { get; set; }
    ...
    [ForeignKey("CodigoCliente")]
    public virtual ClienteProyecto ClienteProyecto { get; set; }
```

**Clase MobileProyecto:**

```
    [Key]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CodigoProyecto { get; set; }
    ...
    [ForeignKey("CodigoProyecto")]
    public virtual ClienteProyecto ClienteProyecto { get; set; }
```

**Clase ClienteProyecto:**

```
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CodigoCliente { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CodigoProyecto { get; set; }
    ...
```

Comment: Gracias. Pero dijo lo mismo :  The relationship from 'MobileCliente.ClienteProyecto' to 'ClienteProyecto.MobileCliente' with foreign key properties {'CodigoCliente' : string} cannot target the primary key {'CodigoCliente' : string, 'CodigoProyecto' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.

Comment: Es como que no entiende como hacer la asociación de la llave principal de cliente con la llave principal de cliente-proyecto porque la llave principal de la clase cliente-proyecto es compuesta, entonces imagino que no sabe a cual de las 2 hacer referencia.

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal De acuerdo, pero eso no lo estás indicando en el Modelo "ClienteProyecto", revisa el código que has puesto en la pregunta.

Comment: Pues vale , que eso es lo que no sé como hacerlo

Comment: Revisa la nueva edición de la respuesta por favor. Verás cómo definir la clave compuesta en el Modelo `ClienteProyecto`.